# Keyword not supported provider

Tags: c#, sql-server

The error I am getting is "Error Keyword not supported: 'providername'" and points to the connection string! I have left a comment on the top of the error within my code below. Any help would be much appreciated.

It seems a very common error when connecting to server db. I tried to use the provider OleDb.OleDbConnection but this also gave me a different exception i.e.  provider is not registered on the local machine!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source = Datasource; Initial Catalog = name; User Id = user; Password = pass; providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;";
    string queryString = "SELECT ID from SERVICE WHERE ServiceNum1 = 1";
    int paramValue = 5;

    //Error Keyword not supported: 'providername'
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", paramValue);
        //try
        //{
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}",
                    reader[0]);
            }
            reader.Close();
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        //}
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing " providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;" from the connection string

Comment: The "...;providername=..." should not be inside the connection string.

Comment: why don't you store the connection string inside of your `App.Config or Web.Config` file take a look at this site for 
[how to configure connection strings in C#](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: When I removed provider name, it gave me this exception: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Comment: Anton Gogolev, where it should be?

Comment: Try to connect to the server from SSMS. If success then place your connection string to App.config as @MethodMan recommended.

Comment: Thank you Alex but how do I make the SSMS connection?